# Recommendation Sought for Data Storage Technique for large dataset of 3D vectors and associated data

Tags: .net, database

I need to handle a large set (10m +) of data points indexed by 2 dimensions, which will comprise X,Y,Z plus some additional cargo data per point (up to 500 bytes per point). I usually use RDBMS and Mongo stores in my work but but neither seem the right solution for this kind of structure. I will need to access the data points by their X,Y coordinates rapidly and in some circumstances for given areas of coverage (i.e. within a polygon) so just using the XY as a compound key might not be sufficient.

I have considered the following data stores (other than SQL Server Compact and Mongo)

1) Fixed record sized data file, for a fixed maxiumum area, allowing offset calculated indexes. Old school programming, but this would work but; requires me to fix my maximum size in order to generate the stride offsets.
2) Individual records of single points, indexed by a compound XY key, thrown into a table store (I know of Azure table storage, but am not familiar with any .net free variants).

The subsystem is written in .net and hosted on Windows, and the data store can be in-process for speed; it will not be updated frequently.

I am looking for a recommendation of a data storage technique that would best suit this problem. In default of any really strong alternative I'd normally just code a fixed fize data file solution but if there are better alternatives ....

Phillip

Comment: @KenWhite - I'm asking a legitimate question about programming techniques and tools to store a specific data type for a specific usage pattern. It can only be a recommendation instead of a "solution" because there is probably no single best answer. I know why the restriction exists, but in this case it is I think a legitimate question to know how best to approach storage of a 2 dimensional data stucture indexed data set.

Comment: "Free product" could easily be a SourceForge library. Not sure thats what your editorial policy is designed to avoid - but have complied anyhow.

Comment: Right-o, please un-close when convenient.